# Trying to share session between domain and sub domain cakephp (session keeps getting reset)

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have similar problem and I've tried every option that has been mentioned so far, I guess there must still be something I'm not doing right because this is just not working for me. Here's what I have and what I've noticed so far - I have a website say (example.com) and a sub-domain (user.example.com). The idea is a user should be able to login from the top domain and not have to login again when s/he goes to any of the sub-domain. Here's my host layout

www/ app/ Controllers/

Model/

Views/

web_root/

sub_domain_root/ Controllers/

Model/

Views/

web_root/

lib/ Cake/*

What happens is this, when I login on the top-domain and go to the sub-domain I can't seem to pick up the user session in the sub-domain. Things get even wilder when I go back to the top-domain from the sub-domain I seem to have lost the user session because even the top-domain can't seem to find it anymore. I suspect that because the two domains are using the same core and when the user navigate to another domain (like the sub) Cake/php sees it as a fresh request to the domain. Please help, this problem is holding me back on my schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is linked to the `session.cookie_domain` directive. You can probably set it through an `ini_set` directive

Unfortunately, I don't have time to check right now if you should have `.example.com` or `example.com` in it (it's different for Javascript & PHP)

Comment: Yea, I tried that, infact I put it all over my Cake app, in Core, in bootstrap and somehow I just couldn't get it to work. I have Security.level set to low. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try setting `Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');` in `core.php`. I remember needing to dig into the security level stuff to figure it out. When it is set to `high` The security code kept resetting the sessions on me without my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not sure the Security.level has much impact on the issue, what I found it that Security.salt in both apps is different and setting it to the same values makes the two domains to now share the same session. How ever I'm still having problems retrieving a session set in the 1st domain from the 2nd domain. I've set the value using Session->write('someValue'); but having problem getting it from the 2nd domain using Session->read('someValue');. Any ideas?